# awk strings for git

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I'm trying to do an awk to retrieve the directory for certain git repos.

Current

```
git@ssh.gitlab.org:repo1/dir/dir/file1.git
git@ssh.gitlab.org:repo1/dir/dir/file2.git
git@ssh.gitlab.org:repo1/dir/dir/file3.git
git@ssh.gitlab.org:repo1/dir/dir/file4.git
```

I have this below using a field separate, but I'm unsure how to remote .git

```
awk -F':' '{print $2}' file
repo1/dir/dir/file1.git
repo1/dir/dir/file2.git
repo1/dir/dir/file3.git
repo1/dir/dir/file4.git
```

Desired result

```
repo1/dir/dir/file1
repo1/dir/dir/file2
repo1/dir/dir/file3
repo1/dir/dir/file4
```

Comment: Can file/folder names contain dots?

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk -F'[:.]' '{print $(NF-1)}'  input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** In case you don't want to hard code field number then try following.

```
awk 'match($0,/:[^.]*/){print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)}' Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
awk -F':' '{sub(/\.[^.\/]*$/, "", $2); print $2;}' file
```

Using `-F':'` you will split all records (lines) into colon-separated fields. You access the second item only using `$2`, but before `print`ing it, you need to remove the final `.` and any 0 or more chars other than `.` and `/` up to the end of the field value, which is done with `sub(/\.[^.\/]*$/, "", $2)`.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/tXNvNw)

With this solution, you may handle files and folders that may have any amount of dots in their names.

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`

```
$ sed 's/^[^:]*://; s/\.git$//' file
repo1/dir/dir/file1
repo1/dir/dir/file2
repo1/dir/dir/file3
repo1/dir/dir/file4
```

- `s/^[^:]*://` remove up to first `:` from start of line
- `s/\.git$//` remove `.git` from end of line
- you can also use `sed -E 's/^[^:]*:|\.git$//g'` to do it with single substitution

Answer (score 0):

With regex, you can use:
`(?<=:)[a-z0-9\/]*`

Match anything composed of letters, numbers and slash after the semicolon. So it will stop at the dot.

Or directly match everything between : and . with

`(?<=:).*(?=\.)`

Comment: fyi: cli tools like `awk` and `sed` do not support lookarounds, so this wouldn't help in this case.. if GNU grep is available with PCRE support, then `grep -oP '(?<=:)[a-z0-9\/]*'` , `grep -oP ':\K[a-z\d\/]*'` etc would work